# Flutter: getApplicationSupportDirectory as a synchronous method

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to use the [network to file](https://pub.dev/packages/network_to_file_image) plugin. Since the images come from my Firebase Storage, it speeks for itself that I do not want to overload my available bandwith so I want to use this pluging to save files locally as to not re-load them everytime.

The problem is, the `Widget` requires a `File` to store it (of course).

```
 NetworkToFileImage(
          url: "http://example.com/someFile.png", 
          file: myFile)
```

But I cannot specify a path, because the only way to get a writable location is through `getApplicationSupportDirectory()` which is an `async` method. A huge workaround would be to make tons of things asynchronous, but it seems weird that getting this location (which is not an IO operation, merely returning a constant String) is asynchronous. In Android Studio with Java for example, getting the folder can be done through synchronously through `context.getFilesDir()`. So why not with Flutter?

Comment: As I know there isn't any other way to get app directory, so getting the file path from parent widget or using an async function is probably the only way.

Comment: call that method in `main`, before runApp & store the `Directory` in some store.